# Peculiarity with Scale and Z-Score

Tags: r

I was attempting to scale my data in R after doing some research on the function (which it seems to follow `(x - mean) / std.dev`. This was just what I was looking for, so I scaled my dataframe in R. I'd also want to make sure my assumptions are correct so that I don't have wrong conclusions.


**Assumption**
R scales each column independently. Therefore, column 1 will have its own mean and standard deviation. Column 2 will have its own.

Assuming I have a dataset of size 100,000 and I scale 3 columns. If I proceed to remove all columns with a Z-Score over 3 and less than -3, I could have **up to** `(100,000 * .003) = 900 rows removed!`

However, when I went to truncate my data, my 100,000 rows were left with 94,798. This means 5,202 rows were removed.

Does this mean my assumption about scale was wrong, and that it doesn't scale by column?

**Update**
So I ran a test and did Z-Score conversion on my own. Still the same amount of columns removed in the end so I believe *scale* does work. Now I'm just curious why more than .3% of the data is removed when 3 standard deviations out are removed.

Comment: That calculation would also be assuming that each of your columns is normally distributed. Did you test that assumption?

Comment: See the [Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) for a non-parametric bound. This puts the upper bound at 1/9 of your data, or 11,111 observations.

Comment: @G5W I did a qqnorm of one of my columns and it's not even close to being a straight diagonal. :( I see. I do have a huge sample size though.

Comment: So,  I think that what you are seeing is that your data has a fat tail,  more data out beyond 3 sd than is typical for a normal distribution.

Comment: Hey, man. Your tails are fat! And huge!

Comment: @G5W I see. I'm trying to do a K-Means plot and eliminate outliers as a result. Is it okay then to truncate this much data?

Comment: I think that more information is needed about your data. Have you looked at density plots?  Is there just one mode to your data? The main reason for clustering at all is to gain an understanding of your data.  It sounds like your data set may require other types of exploration first.